# How to use shell exec grep to search multiple words in a file in php

Tags: php, unix, grep

Here is my code

```
$words=$_GET['word'];
$words=explode(' ',$words);
$words=implode('|',$words);
$search=shell_exec( 'grep -E '.$words.' 
/home/jitu/data.txt');
$search=explode('\n',$search);
foreach($search as $line){echo '<p>'.$line.'</p>';}
```

This code works best for single search word but is not working in multiple words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the $words variable in shell_exec you need to enclose it within quotes.
The '|' (pipe symbol) passes the result of the command on the left to the command on the right.

Your shell is executing this:

```
$: grep -E one|two|three data.txt 
bash: two: command not found
bash: three: command not found
```

When it should be executing this:

```
$: grep -E 'one|two|three' data.txt 
one
two
```

Code:

```
<?php
$words="one two three";
$words=explode(' ',$words);
$words=implode('|',$words);
$search=shell_exec( "grep -E '{$words}' data.txt");
$search=explode('\n',$search);
foreach($search as $line){echo '<p>'.$line.'</p>';};
```

On a side note, as your passing user supplied input to shell_exec without sanitizing it first you are leaving yourself vulnerable to code execution.

Comment: Thank you. It's working.yes,i am sanitizing user input data before executing it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the shell for this is not a good approach. PHP already has functions that can do this. I would use `preg_match_all` and `file_get_contents`. This assumes the file isn't very large, if so `fread` might be needed.

```
$words = $_GET['word'];
$words = explode(' ',$words);
$words = implode('|',$words);
$file = file_get_contents('/home/jitu/data.txt');
preg_match_all('/^.*\b(' . $words . ').*$\b/m', $file, $search);
foreach($search[0] as $line){
     echo '<p>'.$line.'</p>';
}
```

I also added word boundaries to your regex so partial words aren't matched. The `m` modifier is so the `^$` match per line, rather than the whole file. The `.*` is so everything before/after the match will be captured. If you just want to know what terms were matched `$search[1]` can be used.

An additional note, user input should never be passed directly to the shell.

Comment: I don't want to use file get contents function that it takes more RAM resources.

Comment: @Jitu Please read full answer before disregarding. `This assumes the file isn't very large, if so fread might be needed.` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php ... and the shell could have the same memory issues

Comment: There is another problem with preg match with \b regex that It not working with non-English words.

Comment: @Jitu If unicode characters are being used a `u` modifier should be used.

Comment: $search_words="word1|word2|word3";$content= file_get_contents('data.txt');
$lines=explode(PHP_EOL,$content);
foreach($lines as $line){
if(preg_match("/\b($search_words)\b/iu", $line)){ 
$allresults[]=array($line);}} . What's wrong with this code ? It's working fine in English words,but not working with non English words.

Comment: Provide UTF characters for `$content`.

Comment: My data.txt file already written in utf-8 format.and when i removes the \b modifier from preg match function,the code works perfectly with English and non English words.

Comment: Provide example

Comment: I don't have any live example right now.i have already removed the search function from my website where the preg match function was used.Now i want to go with shell exec command to make a script for searching inside the website.